# How can I create fallback language params to every routes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I would like to push a fallback language param to every route if not found in url

for example when I enter:     /page
router should redirect me to: /en/page

how can I do that with nuxt and i18n....?

Answer (score 1):

Add `strategy: "default"` to your `i18n` config in `nuxt.config.js` so it's going to look like this:

```js
//nuxt.config.js
i18n: {
  strategy: "default"
}
```

And now if there won't be a language param in your route a `defaultLocale` language param will be automatically added to your url.